# how does _path in views work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I noticed in a couple of places either in the link_to method or the form_for method, while mentioning the url path, it been simply referred as model_path(eg product_path,users_path, sessions_path). I wanna know how does it exactly works?

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be clear to you if you go to your rails application folder in the console and type **rake routes**. This will show you all the routes in your application, in terms of **_path**.

For example if you have a scaffold for **User**. Then, here's the routes you will have:

```
users_path -> /yourapp/users/index        # route to your index action in the controller
new_user_path -> /yourapp/users/new       # route to your new action in the controller
edit_user_path -> /yourapp/users/:id/edit # route to your edit action in the controller
user_path -> /yourapp/users/:id/show      # route to your show action in the controller
```

I hope it is clear, what you wanted to know.